# Yowsup on ubuntu touch: --enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I have been following [this](http://www.whatsappfor.org/software/whatsapp-ubuntu-phone-touch/) tutorial for trying to install whatsapp client on ubuntu touch. But while installing Pillow, it keeps resulting in error:

```
ValueError: --enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found, aborting
```

I also tried installing `libjpeg` and `zlib` but keeps resulting in same error.

I actually tried running `python setup.py install` so python takes care of dependencies, which leads me to installing Pillow which results in above error.

I also tried manually installing pillow using:

```
pip install Pillow
easy_install Pillow
```

But again, both result in same error as above. Please suggest how do I install pillow in ubuntu touch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install these two libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: Already installed. Still facing this error.